# Conflict occurs while adding a jquery for sticky div in joomla

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need a header that sticks to the top while scrolling down the page. Am using the following jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");

function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top)
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick')
  else
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
  }
// If you have jQuery directly, use the following line, instead
// $(function() {
// If you have jQuery via Google AJAX Libraries
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
  });
</script>
```

but the sliders already present in the page not functioning! Please help me to solve this issue.
I have added `$.noConflict();`above the function the slider works properly and sticky div is not working!

And have made following changes to the code // Start closure to prevent namespace conflicts

```
;(function($) {

// Whatever code you want that relies on $ as the jQuery object

// End closure
})(jQuery);
```

both the slider and sticky div not working!

Comment: let's see what the <head> looks like in your HTMl after page load, I'm guessing because you already have a slider and you're loading jQuery again, that you break the slider.

Comment: Thank you for the comment  Ohgodwhy. How to add without breaking the slider? Am new to php please help me!

Comment: Hi Arunan try this [Using jQuery with Other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)